# MongoDB: Install but unable to Run database

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sockets, mongoose

I have installed mongodb in past and now i didn't know how to run mongodb .
When i run installed command it said it was  already installed and below is the path(/usr/local/Cellar/mongodb/2.6.3). and when i run mongodb command in terminal is says (:mongod: command not found.).

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Ubuntu then try this command , and post your result here .
sudo service mongod start

Answer (score 0):

You can start MongoDB with this command:

```
brew services start mongodb
```

You can then access the databases with the `mongo` command.

Answer (score 0):

You can verify whether mongod is running on port **27017**.

Ensure the location of the binaries is in the PATH variable. So you need to **set path** where you have installed mongodb.

You can find more detailed procedure [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-linux/)